# If three forces act on an object in equilibrium, they must pass through a common point. How does this generalise?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, equilibrium

If three forces act on an object in rotational equilibrium, the line of action of each force must pass through a common point (parallel forces satisfy this as they go through a common point at infinity). My question is, how does this generalise when more than three forces are applied?

Comment: You mean if _only_ three forces are acting, and no external moment is applied. I am correct?

Comment: FYI - A set of _n_-number of forces acting on a body, each on its own line of action, when they meet at a common point is called a [pencil of lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil_(geometry)#Pencil_of_lines).

Answer (score 0):

If an object is in rotational equilibrium, its rotational velocity is constant.  This necessarily requires that no net torque is being applied to the object.  To meet this requirement, all forces on the object must pass through a single point.

Comment: This isn't true in general as you could have, e.g., six pairwise-canceling forces in a triangular arrangement so that no more than four meet at any point.